# discord channel link in message

Tags: python, bots

Using discord.py, I am making a bot to send users a direct message if a keyword of their choosing is mentioned.

Everything is working, except I just want to add the channel they were mentioned in to the message. Here is my code:

```
        print("SENDING MESSAGE")
        sender = '{0.author.name}'.format(message)
        channel = message.channel.name
        server = '{0.server}'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(member, server+": #"+channel+": "+sender+": "+msg)
```

This results in a correct message being composed, but the #channel part of the message is not a clickable link as it would be if i typed it into the chat window myself. Is there a different object I should be feeding into the message?

Comment: For Discord URL needs, to begin withs `http://` and if the site has an SSL certificate `https://`

Comment: Are you saying in a discord message, when you type #channel to someone, it is embedding a URL into that statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Discord: there is channel mention.
Try that way,  do `message.channel.mention` instead of `message.channel.name`
it should able to link a channel in PM or everywhere.

Source: [Discord Documentation](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Channel.mention)

Comment: Awesome! Idk why it didn't occur to me that the mention was the key part of it. Thanks!